# how to layout two buttons beside each other with a gap in between

Tags: android

Apologies if this seems obvious but cannot seem to get it right. I have two buttons next to each other and the upload button is actually in the center. What I actually want is a 10dp gap between these two buttons and I want the gap between them to be in the centre. How can I do this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bak"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/button_back"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/upload_button"
        android:background="@drawable/love_heart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upload_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/button_upload"
        android:background="@drawable/love_heart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a much better solution.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="b1"
    android:layout_weight=".5"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="b1"
    android:layout_weight=".5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

You can add padding to it if you want... but using a linearlayout is a much easier and a better way to handle this "issue"

Comment: "much easier and a better way" is what I don't seem to agree with.

Comment: @MbuodileObiosio why is that? what would be your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a view inbetween:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bak"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/button_back"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view"
        android:background="@drawable/love_heart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upload_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view"
        android:text="@string/button_upload"
        android:background="@drawable/love_heart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```